# Shortcut key for Preview on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, quicklook

Coming from OS X to Windows 8.1 I miss QuickLook.  I noticed that in the right click menu in Explorer there's a Preview item for some file types, such as images.  Is there a shortcut key to invoke this function, so I don't have to reach for the mouse and click twice each time?  Is there a different built-in way to get a simple practical alternative to OS X's QuickLook?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> will open the selected item with the default program. If its an image, it will be opened with your image editor/viewer.

Alternatively, you can enable the preview pane on the right, which means that every file that is an image is shown there.

There's an icon in the toolbar you can click to activate the preview pane, but <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> also activates it.

Another option is to use different icons (medium icons and up). Then the thumpnail of the icon will become a little preview.

`Rightclick` -> `View` -> choose the one you want.

Comment: +1 for the shortcut `Alt+P`. You can browse the files and if necessary, get a quick look at the document with this shortcut.